# Facebook: Can set the description and image of an event using the graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to create events on behalf of the user using the Graph API.

But by looking at this URL (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api), the only parameters available are: name, start_time, end_time.

What?! I need to place the description and image too.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095099/attach-image-to-facebook-event-php-sdk-rest-or-graph-api   - it's made by the php-sdk but hopefully you can achieve the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. Since I found many people searching for this solution, I posted the code to [create an event with image using the facebook C# SDK](http://stoodit.com/2011/02/create-events-using-facebook-c-sdk-upload-a-photo/).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the event publish API will accept the description parameter, it is probably just not documented. Have you tried to pass it in?

If that doesn't work, just use the rest API. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.create/

Comment: Hi Nathan, only now I was to check your answer. I'll try the description in a few minutes, but the problem is in the picture. I tried doing something like in this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095099/attach-image-to-facebook-event-php-sdk-rest-or-graph-api) but the picture parameter is giving me problems. I also tried doing the way we upload photos following the example you gave in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210746/c-facebook-graph-how-to-upload-to-album-id/4211343#4211343.

How do I that? Can you please give a link to an example?

Comment: I found a way to this. If you want, please feel free to make the code in my answer available in the Facebook C# SDK documentation.