# C# & Facebook API

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm currently using the Facebook API and C#.

What i'm trying to do is upload an image to an event.

I've tried two methods, but neither seem to work. Could someone please take a look.

**Method 1**

```
        Dictionary<string, string> args = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string source = "@test.jpg";
        string relpath = "/1234456789/photos";
        args.Add("message", "sssssss");
        args.Add("access_token", api.AccessToken);
        args.Add("source", source);
        api.Post(relpath, args);
```

**Method 2**

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("http://graph.facebook.com/1234456789/photos")); 
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"; 
        request.Method = "POST";

        string path = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("test.jpg");
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(ar => 
        { 
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter((ar.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetRequestStream(ar))) 
            { 
                writer.Write("{0}={1}&", "message", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Test")); 
                writer.Write("{0}=@{1}&", "source", path);
                writer.Write("{0}={1}", "access_token",
                    api.AccessToken); 
            } 
        }, request);
```

**Method 3**

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        byte[] responseBinary = client.UploadFile("http://localhost:61689/Widgets/test2.aspx", "POST", @"C:\test.jpg");

        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBinary);

        Dictionary<string, string> args = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        string relpath = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture";
        args.Add("message", "sssssss");
        args.Add("access_token", GetAccessToken(code));
        args.Add("source", response); 

        api.Post(relpath, args);
```

In method 3 i'm trying to create the response and write that. I'm getting 400 bad request.

The image 'test.jpg' currently sits in my website root, same as the page calling it.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you get any errors?

Comment: 400 bad request for method 1, method 2 just runs through but i don't get any image on facebook. Hope this helps.

Comment: The following question may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210746/c-facebook-graph-how-to-upload-to-album-id.

Comment: Thats a different SDK, it should just be a standard post but isn't working. Will keep looking or will have to implement the sdk in the link. cheers.

Comment: I see. **Tip** When replying directly to another user's comment who did not ask the question or provide an answer, include their @username and they will get notified. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Robert, not sure if this is what is causing it, but in Example 1 it looks like you are trying to use a string literal on the JPG name, but if so, the @ symbol needs to be outside the quotes...

> @"good morning"  // a string literal

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only passing the filename of the photo to upload.  Are you using a library that will read the actual photo contents from disk?  If not, you'll need to do that yourself and write the contents to the request.

The format for writing the photo contents to the request will depend on the expectations of the API you are writing to (multi-part, etc.).

Comment: Thats what method 2 is trying to do.

Comment: @Robert - In method 2, I don't see where you're actually writing the file contents.  I see writing the file name, but not actually writing the file contents.