# How to post photo to album in facebook graph api Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

i wrote an application for facebook but i couldn't upload image to album that i created,
code is in below, thanks for your help.

```
        Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(GetAccessToken());
        Dictionary<string, string> album = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        album.Add("name", "Test Album");
        album.Add("message", "Message here!");
        JSONObject result = api.Post("me/albums", album);
        string AlbumId = result.Dictionary["id"].String;

        Dictionary<string, string> photo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        photo.Add("message", "test Message");
        photo.Add("source", "tgw.jpg");
        JSONObject photoResult = api.Post("/" + AlbumId + "/photos", photo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this works for you?

```
string photoPath = @"..\..\..\Facebook.Tests\bin\Release\monkey.jpg";
            string albumId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AlbumId"];
            byte[] photo = File.ReadAllBytes(photoPath);

            FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.access_token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessToken"];
            parameters.message = "This is a test photo of a monkey that has been uploaded " +
                                 "by the Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com)" +
                                 "using the Graph API";
            var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
            {
                FileName = "monkey.jpg",
                ContentType = "image/jpeg",
            };
            mediaObject.SetValue(photo);
            parameters.source = mediaObject;

            dynamic result = app.Api(String.Format("/{0}/photos", albumId), parameters, HttpMethod.Post);
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210746/c-facebook-graph-how-to-upload-to-album-id)

Comment: I don't have a app.Api method i thought our sdk's are different :( mine is https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

Comment: I think you should really really switch to this microsoft's SDK http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

it is just Great