# Uploading photos to Facebook album via Facebook C# SDK

Tags: vb.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to upload photos to facebook album with the aid of Facebook C# SDK ver. 5.4.1.0, but keep failing with the following error: "OAuthException) (#200) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Get Facebook PageID for a certain page, whose Admin I am
- Create an image album on that page
- Upload photos to that album

So far I managed to get Access Token for the page, and create an album inside that page

The code is:

```
    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    Dim fb As New Facebook.FacebookClient("MyAccessToken")
    Dim dic As IDictionary(Of String, Object) = DirectCast(fb.Get("/me/accounts"), IDictionary(Of String, Object)) 'List of all my pages
    Dim dicy As IList(Of Object) = DirectCast(dic("data"), IList(Of Object)) 'cast the Data part of JSON to list
    Dim page As IDictionary(Of String, Object)      'Individual item inside the dicy :)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dicy.Count - 1
        page = DirectCast(dicy(i), IDictionary(Of String, Object))
        If page("id") = PageID Then 'try to match given PageID with the one in the list
            fb.AccessToken = page("access_token") 'change access token to the one of the page
            Exit For
        End If


    Next

    'Create an album
    Dim fbparams As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    fbparams.Add("message", "New album")
    fbparams.Add("name", "my album name")
    'post to Facebook and get the AlbumID
    Dim Album As Facebook.JsonObject = fb.Post("/me/albums", fbparams)

    'try to upload photos
    Call UploadPhotoToAlbum(fb, Album(0).ToString, Server.MapPath("~/myimage.jpg"))
End Sub
```

And the code which uploads file is:

```
    Private Sub UploadPhotoToAlbum(ByVal fbApp As Facebook.FacebookClient, ByVal AlbumID As String, ByVal ImagePath As String)
    Dim media As New Facebook.FacebookMediaObject
    media.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    media.FileName = ImagePath

    Dim filebytes As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath)
    media.SetValue(filebytes)
    Dim upload As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    upload.Add("name", "Picture No 1")
    upload.Add("message", "This is my first uploaded image")
    upload.Add("@file.jpg", media)
    fbApp.Post("/" & AlbumID, upload)
End Sub
```

My App has the following permissions:create_note manage_pages offline_access photo_upload publish_stream read_stream share_item status_update user_photo_video_tags user_photos user_videos video_upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to solve, found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5452767/1023383)

I forgot to put "/photos" in the last fbApp.Post sentence.

Comment: +1 for a nice question structure, and taking the time to answer your own question when you solved it!